# If function value for cell with text boxes

Tags: excel, vba

I have two text boxes here. The first has the value 1 to 10 and the second 1 to 2. Depending on the combination of values in the text boxes, I want the cell e. g. E6 to take on a certain value from another sheet. I have tried to approach this step by step, but I can't find a useful solution.

The text boxes:

[image]

The possible value combinations from another sheet:

[image]

e.g.

TextBox1 value = 1 and TextBox2 value = 1 -> Cell E6 = 3,25

TextBox1 value = 2 and TextBox2 value = 2 -> Cell E6 = 13

TextBox1 value = 3 and TextBox2 value = 2 -> Cell E6 = 19,50
and so on

basic idea that has not worked so far:

```
Sub Test()
    
    If TextBox1.Value = ("1") And TextBox2.Value = ("1") Then
    Range("E6").Value = 3.25
    End If
    
    
End Sub
```

maybe someone has a much better solution for this instead of the if function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next way, please:

```
If Me.TextBox1.Value = 1 And Me.TextBox2.Value = 1 Then
    Range("E6").Value = 3.25
End If
```

It will change the range value of the **active worksheet""...

Comment: and can i add like 10+ if functions for the others values without problems? or would it be better to work with s reference?

Comment: @Qncy: Why not? But can you confirm that the above code worked?

Comment: it works. however, it does not update automatically, only when i press F5. is there an option to adjust the value as soon as I change a number?

Comment: @Qncy: Yes. Please, use the text box `Change` Event... Try using `If ... ElseIf ... Else ... End If` in a logical way...

Answer (score 0):

Qncy,

If you're willing to change your data table format as follows:
[image]

Then you can use this function to fill in your answers:

```
Option Explicit

Function GetValue() As Double

'Function Call: =GetValue() in the cell where you want the answer.

  Dim rng As Range
  
  Application.Volatile
  
  Set rng = Application.Caller()
  
  GetValue = Sheets("Data").Range("$A$2").Offset(rng.Offset(0, -2), rng.Offset(0, -1))
  
End Function
```

Of course you'll substitute the textbox values for my .Offset(rng.Offset(0, -2), rng.Offset(0, -1) above, as well as the sheet name, e.g. "Data"

I filled in this table using the function in column C:

[image]

HTH

Ok, here's an example with TextBoxes. I've used the LinkedCell property to link the value into the cell behind the textbox to make referencing easier.

```
Option Explicit

Function GetValue() As Double

  Dim rng As Range
  Dim wks As Worksheet
  
  Application.Volatile
  
  Set rng = Application.Caller()
  Set wks = Sheets("Boxes")
  
  GetValue = Sheets("Data").Range("$A$2").Offset(wks.Cells(1, 1), wks.Cells(1, 2))
  
End Function 'GetValue()
```

Workbook Setup:
[image]

Here's a [link so you can download the test file](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkD_lgup37RQuk2NgzBZPeciiJbT?e=IiK9GX) and see how things are setup:

Comment: Thank you. I will try it asap. But i need 2 text boxes because i simulate a kind of gear shift and the output value should be the speed that changes in a cell depending on the gear. i hope i could describe it well. @RetiredGeek

Comment: I should have added this explicitly:  GetValue = Sheets("Data").Range("$A$2").Offset(Me.Textbox1.Value, Me.Textbox2.Value)

Comment: Thank you very much, but i dont get this one work. sorry.